# Trying to push using bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

Getting started with bot framework and trying to "push" a message to user. I copied some code from a previous post here using SendToConversationAsync and pasting in ids, etc from the emulator but it's not sending. I've pasted the code below. Any help appreciated.

```
namespace Bot
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {    
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                // calculate something for us to return
                int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

                //create reply here

                // return our reply to the user
                Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent **{activity.Text}** which was {length} characters");
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

                SendMessage("Blah!");
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }    

        private void SendMessage(string msg)
        {
            var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "", id: "default-user");
            var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "Bot", id: "m374hm6j2b474lei9");
            var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("http://localhost:3979/"));

            // conversationId for Real Bot
            //var conversationId = connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount).Result;

    // conversationId for Bot Emulator
    //var conversationId = _activityHistory.Conversation;

            IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            message.From = botAccount;
            message.Recipient = userAccount;
            message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: "0dkmb2e3lf1dn2g69");
            message.Text = msg;
            message.Locale = "en-Us";
            connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
        }
    }
}
```

More info:

JSON

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "text": "test",
  "from": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "User"
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "timestamp": "2017-06-02T21:33:24.737Z",
  "channelData": {
    "clientActivityId": "1496437792941.9667812978932935.10"
  },
  "id": "hfncb55l7j7ea0c26",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "localTimestamp": "2017-06-02T14:33:24-07:00",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "m374hm6j2b474lei9",
    "name": "Bot"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "icn5ed433edc0kh99"
  },
  "serviceUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:56303"
}
```

SendMessage:

```
private void SendMessage(string msg)
{
    var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "User", id: "default-user");
    var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "Bot", id: "m374hm6j2b474lei9");
    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("http://localhost:3979/"));

    // conversationId for Real Bot
    //var conversationId = connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount).Result;

    // conversationId for Bot Emulator
    //var conversationId = _activityHistory.Conversation;

    IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
    message.From = botAccount;
    message.Recipient = userAccount;
    message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: "icn5ed433edc0kh99");
    message.Text = msg;
    message.Locale = "en-Us";
    //message.Type = "message";
    //message.ChannelId = "emulator";
    //message.ReplyToId = "62ehe9jk6kn2eg23i";
    message.ServiceUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:56303";

    connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
}
```

Comment: I'm not saying all these are needed, but I do set them in my own working version of this and you don't set them: `message.Type`, `message.ChannelId`, `message.ReplyToId`, and `message.ServiceUrl`.

Comment: Note also that you may need to explicitly trust the URL - `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(botServiceURL);`

Comment: sounds like you are looking for "pro-active messages". Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-template-proactive -- Code example: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages -- [Send proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages)

Comment: Here's another code example for .NET SDK - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding message.Type, message.ChannelID, etc. to no avail. It appears MicrosoftAppCredentials does not have a TrustServiceUrl method.

Comment: did you set `user_id` correctly in userAccount? As I see you've set it into the constant value. It might be changes during the test. I suggest, set it from what you get from Activity in an interaction.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:3979/ is not a valid service url.  That is the url the bot is hosted on, not the url you use to communicate to a user from the bot.

Please look at the POST of a conversation update event in the emulator.

```
[13:05:10] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate]
```

In the Details pane you'll see the serviceUrl near the bottom.  This is the url the emulator is listening on, and the one you would use to communicate to the user from the bot.  ServiceUrl should be cached from a previous activity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I think I'm going to go with using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs. They've got some examples on github with a push that works on a timer and that's working for me. [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage/RootDialog.cs)